# API on a C++ soft

Tags: java, c++, api

I would like to know how to do to get variables of a C++ running program from my Java application. I think I have to do an API, but I don't know how to start this. In fact, I want to get information about packets in the Ekiga softphone. I localized what I want in Ekiga's `main.cpp` :

```
double lost = mw->priv->current_call->get_lost_packets();
double late = mw->priv->current_call->get_late_packets();
double out_of_order = mw->priv->current_call->get_out_of_order_packets();
```

Comment: You can use JNI, but not sure what you meant by "do an API" or "localized what I want". If you just want to capture SIP packets then you can use wireshark or something similar.

Comment: @AJG85 : No,I just want to get number of lost and late packets while I'm in my Java middleware.

Answer (score 2):

I think what you need is JNI: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Native_Interface

You have to create an dll that will have methods that return this values and have a java class with native methods that will use this dll.

Answer (score 1):

Sound like you want to implement a bridge layer using technologies such [JNI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Native_Interface) or [JNA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Native_Access).
A second option would be writing a [Web service](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_service) or [Message passing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_passing) layer between the two languages. I would avoid [CORBA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Object_Request_Broker_Architecture) for such a simple problem (actually, I would avoid CORBA period hehehe).
Either that or have the C++ write the data to a Database, File, etc and write Java code to read it.

Answer (score 1):

You can't directly access c++ variables from a different process. I do not know if ekiga already provides a way to get the data from external programs, so here are a few ways to get at the data (all involve modifying ekiga itself in some way).

- Add a socket to listen for connections within the ekiga program and make your java program connect to this socket using client sockets. This way you can send the information to the connected java program wenever these values change.
- Start the java Program within ekiga or make your java program start ekiga as a native method call. Both of these involve jni and result in both parts (ekiga and java program) running as a single process.

The first is simpler and less error prone, however you need some basic knowledge about network programming in both java and c++.